# Name is not defined but earlier it worked, now it doesn't; Exact same code

Tags: python-3.x

Newbie at Python here and am practicing some questions online.
Somehow after working on another question, this code does not work anymore when it was the exact same code

```
def diff(a):
    a = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    if a > 17:
        return (a-17)*2
    else:
        return
diff(a)
```

Comment: Outside the function `diff`, the name `a` is not defined.

Comment: Ahhh silly me haha
But for some reason I remember not having defined the variable outside of the function; Oh wells, thanks!

Comment: Oh, it seems like after removing the define of a, whatever value I input works now
Not sure why, maybe it's the compiler that's caching or something